# Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a newsletter API using java spring framework. Whenever I am hitting the API as a post with request model getting this excetion org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.

This is my newsletter model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ns_newsletters")
public class Newsletter extends DomainObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "newsletter_gen")
@TableGenerator(name = "newsletter_gen", table = "ns_newsletter_id_gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "NewsletterId_Gen", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "subscriber_id")
private int subscriberId;

@Column(name = "subscriber_email_address")
private String subscriberEmailAddress;

@Column(name = "is_subscribe")
public boolean isSubscribe;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "gender")
private String gender;

@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "ns_newsletter_mailer_list_linkage", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "newsletter_mailer_id")})
private Set<NewsletterMailerList> mailerLists;


public Newsletter() {
    super();
}

public Newsletter(String createdBy, Timestamp creationDate, int version, Timestamp lastModifiedDate,
                  String lastModifiedBy, RecordStatus recordStatus) {
    super(createdBy, creationDate, version, lastModifiedDate, lastModifiedBy, recordStatus);
}

 public Newsletter(Set<NewsletterMailerList> mailerLists, int subscriberId, String subscriberEmailId, boolean isSubscribe, String firstName, String lastName, String sex) {
    super();
    this.subscriberId = subscriberId;
    this.subscriberEmailAddress = subscriberEmailId;
    this.isSubscribe = isSubscribe;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gender = sex;
    this.mailerLists = mailerLists;
}

public int getSubscriberId() {
    return subscriberId;
}

public void setSubscriberId(int subscriberId) {
    this.subscriberId = subscriberId;
}

public String getSubscriberEmailAddress() {
    return subscriberEmailAddress;
}

public void setSubscriberEmailAddress(String subscriberEmailAddress) {
    this.subscriberEmailAddress = subscriberEmailAddress;
}

public boolean isSubscribe() {
    return isSubscribe;
}

public void setSubscribe(boolean subscribe) {
    isSubscribe = subscribe;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Set<NewsletterMailerList> getMailerLists() {
    return mailerLists;
}

public void setMailerLists(Set<NewsletterMailerList> mailerLists) {
    this.mailerLists = mailerLists;
}
}
```

This is my NewsletterMailerList model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ns_newsletter_mailer_list")
public class NewsletterMailerList extends DomainObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "newsletter_mailer_list_gen")
@TableGenerator(name = "newsletter_mailer_list_gen", table = "ns_newsletter_mailer_list_id_gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "NewsletterMailerList_Gen", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "newsletter_mailer_id")
private int newsletterMailerId;

@Column(name = "mailer_list_name")
private String mailerListName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "mailerLists")
private Set<Newsletter> newsletters;

public Set<Newsletter> getNewsletter() {
    return newsletters;
}

public void setNewsletter(Set<Newsletter> newsletters) {
    this.newsletters = newsletters;
}

public int getNewsletterMailerId() {
    return newsletterMailerId;
}

public void setNewsletterMailerId(int newsletterMailerId) {
    this.newsletterMailerId = newsletterMailerId;
}

public String getMailerListName() {
    return mailerListName;
}

public void setMailerListName(String mailerListName) {
    this.mailerListName = mailerListName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Set<Newsletter> getNewsletters() {
    return newsletters;
}

public void setNewsletters(Set<Newsletter> newsletters) {
    this.newsletters = newsletters;
}
}
```

I give contain type as application/json.
I am new to do this kind of stuff. Please help me why I am getting this error. If you need anything more let me know.

This is Newsletter Controller

```
package com.neostencil.modules.newslettermanagement.controller;


import com.neostencil.framework.base.BaseResponse;
import com.neostencil.framework.enums.StatusType;
import com.neostencil.framework.utilities.common.CollectionUtil;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1")
@Api(value = "Newsletter", description = "Rest API for Newsletter 
operations", tags = "Newsletter API")
public class NewsletterController {

@Autowired
NewsletterService newsletterService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/newsletters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> addNewsletter(RequestEntity<SingleNewsletterRequest> request) {

    ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> response = null;
    BaseResponse baseResponse = new BaseResponse();
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    if (request.getBody() == null) {
        baseResponse.setStatus(StatusType.NOT_FOUND);
        messages.add("Newsletter request is empty or null");
        baseResponse.setMessages(messages);
        response = new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse>(baseResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        Newsletter newsletter = request.getBody().getNewsletter();
        Set<NewsletterMailerList> mailerLists = request.getBody().getNewsletter().getMailerLists();

        if (CollectionUtil.isEmpty(mailerLists) || !mailerLists.contains(MailerListType.list_1) || !mailerLists.contains(MailerListType.list_2)) {
            NewsletterMailerList newsletterMailerList1 = new NewsletterMailerList();
            newsletterMailerList1.setMailerListName(MailerListType.list_1);

            NewsletterMailerList newsletterMailerList2 = new NewsletterMailerList();
            newsletterMailerList2.setMailerListName(MailerListType.list_2);

            mailerLists.add(newsletterMailerList1);
            mailerLists.add(newsletterMailerList2);

            newsletter.setMailerLists(mailerLists);
        }


        newsletterService.addNewsletter(newsletter);
        baseResponse.setStatus(StatusType.SUCCESSFUL);
        messages.add("Newsletter added successfully");
        baseResponse.setMessages(messages);
        response = new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse>(baseResponse, HttpStatus.OK);


    }

    return response;


}
}
```

This is request  class

```
public class SingleNewsletterRequest {

Newsletter newsletter;

public Newsletter getNewsletter() {
    return newsletter;
}

public void setNewsletter(Newsletter newsletter) {
    this.newsletter = newsletter;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show your handler method from your controller and It will be nice also to see your servlet configuration. There is nothing to do with these entity.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I have added the controller. I am not able to find the servlet configuration file in my project.

Comment: Thats not your Controller you gave us. You need to first know how Spring MVC works. If you dont know what is what, know them first. You can see this  https://dzone.com/articles/how-spring-mvc-really-works

Comment: Add default constructor to request entity. Else add `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and make sure you're sending json value with valid headers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue occurred due to some functional methods of the DTO have the names that follow Java Beans naming conventions, e.g. isValid().

It was absent in a request json-representation and then, when it's deserialized in back-end side the issue occurred.

So, try to check if any Java Beans methods (get*, set*, is*) has no their counterparts in respective front-end objects and avoid such methods (I've just changed the name to simply valid()).

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your POST method add the consumes attribute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newsletters", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> addNewsletter(RequestEntity<SingleNewsletterRequest> request) {
....
}
```

this will assumes that the HTTP request you are creating actually has

`Content-Type:application/json` instead of `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50567626/8956733

Try to remove `@JsonManagedReference`

A bit weird, but it did help me as well (see my comment below).